# Connect to ONLINE MySQL database using DSN ODBC

Tags: mysql, database, odbc, database-connection, dsn

I am connecting an online MySQL database.

I have downloaded MySQL ODBC Connector 5.1. Now am trying to setup the DSN. But am getting the error:

```
Connection Failed : [HY000] [MySQL] [ODBC 5.1 Driver]Access Denied for user 'user123'@'myweb.com'
```

I have hosted this site with some hosting provider. Do i need some details from the provider????

I am doing this > Control Panel--->Administrative Tools--->Data Sources (ODBC)--->Then i chose MySQL ODBC Driver 5.1-----> then i enter the following in the DIALOG which pops-up:

**TCP/IP Server**  - www.myweb.com 
**Port =3306**

**userid=user123 and password** , I enter those userid=user123 & password which i enter when i open www.myweb.com/cpanel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cpanel by default does not allow remote connections. 
Please go to database area in your cPanel and add there your public IP address so that it can accept connection requests from your IP address.

Comment: Its called "Remote MySQL" under "Databases" in cPanel. Either use your IP if its static or you may wish to use a wild card.